# Computing A Double Integral where x and y are part of a specific region.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, riemann-integration

Compute the following double integral:
$$
\iint\limits_{G} \sqrt{x^{2} - y^{2}} \, dx\, dy,
$$
where
$$
G=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R_{+}^{2}}: 0 \leq x + y \leq 2, 0 \leq x - y \leq 2\} 
$$
In order to solve this question, I wanted to use the following substitutions
$$
u = x + y, v = x-y
$$
This resulted in an answer of $16/9$. However, according to the answer in my book the correct value is $8/9$. This seems to be the result of $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R_{+}^{2}}$ which cuts the rectangle in half but I don't know how to write this down using proper mathematical notation. I was hoping somebody could help me with this double integral.

Exact Steps:
$$
\iint\limits_{G} \sqrt{x^{2} - y^{2}} \, dx\, dy \\
\iint\limits_{G} \sqrt{(x-y)(x+y)} \, dx\, dy \\
\iint\limits_{G} \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{(x-y)(x+y)} \, 2 \, dx\, dy, \\
\iint\limits_{\widetilde{G}} \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{vu} \, du\, dv, \\
\frac{1}{2} \iint\limits_{\widetilde{G}} \sqrt{vu} \, du\, dv, \\
\frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{2} \sqrt{v} \left( \int_{0}^{2} \sqrt{u} \, du \right) \,dv \\
\frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{2} \sqrt{v} \left(\left[\frac{2}{3}u^{\frac{3}{2}}\right]_{0}^{2} \right) \,dv \\
\frac{1}{3}2^{\frac{3}{2}} \int_{0}^{2} \sqrt{v} \,dv \\
\frac{1}{3}2^{\frac{3}{2}} \left[\frac{2}{3}v^{\frac{3}{2}}\right]_{0}^{2} \\
\frac{2}{9}2^3 \\
\frac{16}{9}
$$

Comment: If you share your exact steps, it might be easier to see where you went wrong

Comment: Did u multiply the integral by $detD\phi$ where $\phi$ would be your substitution? That could change it by a factor of 2

Comment: Hint: How would the result change if you used $y\in \mathbb{R}_-$?

Comment: I added the workings as requested.

Comment: Since $y>0$ you must have $u>v$ so the limits on the $u$ integral go from $v$ to $2$

Comment: In the $(u,v)$ plane you integrate over a square. What happens when you map the vertices of this square back to the $(x,y)$ plane?

Comment: Ahh, I think I understand your comment WW1. Thank you so much! Also user170231, This results in a diamond but the actual structure in the (x,y) plane is a triangle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bounds of the integral should be different:

$$\frac{1}{2}\int_0^2\int_v^2\sqrt{uv}\ du\ dv$$

If we just look at the region $\mathbb{R}^2_+$, we have
[image]

Adding in the bounds $0 \leq x + y \leq 2$ and $0 \leq x - y \leq 2$, we have
[image]

The region in the original problem would be the triangle, whereas the region
$$0 \leq u = x + y\leq 2 \\0 \leq v = x-y\leq 2$$
would be the square where the blue and green regions overlap.

To remove the half of the triangle below the $x$-axis, we need to add the bound
$$y \geq 0 \iff 2y \geq 0 \iff u - v \geq 0 \iff u \geq v$$
which gives the correct region,

$$v \leq u = x + y\leq 2 \\0 \leq v = x-y\leq 2$$
or equivalently
$$0 \leq u = x + y\leq 2 \\0 \leq v = x-y\leq u$$
(depending on the order of integration).

Comment: Thank you so much, I understand it much better now!